# Java Message Consumer Hangs/Freezes After Reaching maxConcurrentConsumers

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, activemq-classic

Java Spring servlet application running in Tomcat on Linux.

I have a simple consumer that grabs messages from ActiveMQ and processes the data into a DB. In almost all conditions the number of consumers sits at 2, and it might go up to 3 in some situations. However, in some rare instances I see the the number of consumers hit the maxConcurrentConsumers (which is set to 10). At some point after this no more messages continue to be processed. Messages are generated at about once every second or so (at the most), so this isn't a situation where 1000s of messages are enqueued every second.

The only time I'm able to reproduce the behaviour is by running the application in debug mode from my IDE and then pausing the execution for a moment, and then resuming. This will cause the application to resume, I can hit the various endpoints such as /status, which returns the current status and that it's running. However, no more messages will be consumed and the number of consumers are stuck at until the Tomcat instance is killed and restarted.

The receiver class:

```
@Component
public class Receiver implements MessageListener
{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        logger.trace("entering onMessage");

        if (message instanceof TextMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                String textMessage = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                processMessage(textMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.error("failed to process message", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.10.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:property-placeholder />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="app.consumer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.myapp.consumer.Receiver" />

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.consumer" />

</beans>
```

I've come across this post: [ActiveMQ Consumer Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017721/activemq-consumer-hangs) but I don't think it applies here. When the hang occurs I don't see any significant increase in memory usage in the system or the jvm. I haven't tried increasing the number of consumers as I don't think that's a solution, since it's not a processing volume issue.